Walkthrough animation CAShapeLayer x UIBezierPath
Good afternoon!
I have a problem with animation in the function addHoleToMovableView.
When trying the slow animation from point A to point B, I have not obtained a satisfactory result. I hope to have a very short animation of the type that moves from one place to another on the y-axis from top to bottom or bottom to top. It's as if it moves from one point to another with defined seconds.
My controller:
import UIKit

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController {
    var tutorialView: TutorialView!
    var view1: UIView!
    var view2: UIView!
    var view3: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        tutorialView = TutorialView()
        tutorialView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tutorialView.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
 
        setViews()
        view.addSubview(tutorialView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tutorialView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tutorialView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tutorialView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tutorialView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        tutorialView.onNextButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
        }
        
        tutorialView.onPreviousButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
        }
        
        tutorialView.onOkButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.tutorialView.currentState += 1
            self?.removeTutorialViewFromSuperView()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
    }
    
    private func addHoleToMovableView(frame: CGRect) {
        let holeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.tutorialView.bounds)
        let holePath = UIBezierPath(rect: frame)
        
        path.append(holePath.reversing())
        holeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        holeLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        self.tutorialView.layer.mask = holeLayer
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "patch")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
        holeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "positionAnimation")
    }


    func setViews() {
        view1 = UIView()
        view2 = UIView()
        view3 = UIView()
        
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view1.backgroundColor = .blue
        view2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view3.backgroundColor = .green
        
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
        view.addSubview(view3)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            view2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            
            view3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            view3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            view3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            view3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            
            
        ])
    }
    
    func removeTutorialViewFromSuperView() {
        tutorialView.removeFromSuperview()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    func moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition() {
        switch tutorialView.currentState {
        case 0:
            tutorialView.updateControlContainerConstraints(position: .below, referenceFrame: view1.frame)
            addHoleToMovableView(frame: view1.frame)
        case 1:
            tutorialView.updateControlContainerConstraints(position: .below, referenceFrame: view2.frame)
            addHoleToMovableView(frame: view2.frame)
        case 2:
            tutorialView.updateControlContainerConstraints(position: .above, referenceFrame: view3.frame)
            addHoleToMovableView(frame: view3.frame)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
}

This is currently the "blinking" effect.
Simulator

Everything you are doing with CABasicAnimation is wrong so I'm not surprised you're not seeing any animation.

@matt the animation somehow works, but the effect is just missing. Thanks for the comment .

To animate a path - whether it's for drawing or to use as a mask - we need to set the .toValue for the animation.
The keyPath also needs to be "path" instead of "patch" (but I'm guessing that was a typo):
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
    
    // fromValue is not strictly necessary here, but we use it for consistency
    animation.fromValue = curPath
    animation.toValue = newPath
    
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    // adjust animation speed as desired
    animation.duration = 0.75
    
    holeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "positionAnimation")

We also want to use CATransaction with a completion block, because we need to update the holeLayer.path when the animation ends.
I think you'll also find it much easier to keep the "hole layer" and animation code inside the overlay view (your TutorialView).
Here is some sample code, based on your example, with modifications:
enum ControlPosition {
    case above, below
}

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var tutorialView: TutorialView = TutorialView()
    
    var view1: UIView!
    var view2: UIView!
    var view3: UIView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        setViews()
        
        tutorialView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tutorialView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tutorialView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tutorialView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tutorialView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tutorialView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tutorialView.onNextButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
        }
        
        tutorialView.onPrevButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
        }

        tutorialView.onDoneButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.removeTutorialViewFromSuperView()
        }

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // let the translucent tutorial view show up to begin with
        
        // start with the "hole" above the top of the vivew
        tutorialView.updateHole(.init(x: 0.0, y: -20.0, width: tutorialView.frame.width, height: 20.0), animated: false, cPos: .above)
        
        // then animate
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            self.moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition()
        })
        
    }
    
    func setViews() {
        view1 = UIView()
        view2 = UIView()
        view3 = UIView()
        
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view1.backgroundColor = .blue
        view2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view3.backgroundColor = .green
        
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
        view.addSubview(view3)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            view2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            
            view3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            view3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            view3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            view3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func removeTutorialViewFromSuperView() {
        tutorialView.removeFromSuperview()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    func moveMovableViewToCurrentPosition() {
        switch tutorialView.currentState {
        case 0:
            tutorialView.updateHole(view1.frame, animated: true, cPos: .below)
        case 1:
            tutorialView.updateHole(view2.frame, animated: true, cPos: .below)
        case 2:
            tutorialView.updateHole(view3.frame, animated: true, cPos: .above)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
}

class TutorialView: UIView {
    
    var onNextButtonTapped: (()->())?
    var onPrevButtonTapped: (()->())?
    var onDoneButtonTapped: (()->())?
    
    var currentState: Int = 0

    let translucentLayer = CALayer()
    let holeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    var curPath: CGPath!
    var newPath: CGPath!
    
    let controlContainer = UIView()
    let prevBtn = UIButton()
    let nextBtn = UIButton()
    let doneBtn = UIButton()
    let infoLabel = UILabel()
    
    var ccTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        holeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        holeLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        translucentLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(translucentLayer)
        
        controlContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(controlContainer)
        
        ccTop = controlContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ccTop,
            controlContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            controlContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            controlContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
        ])
        
        prevBtn.setTitle("Voltar", for: [])
        nextBtn.setTitle("Próximo", for: [])
        doneBtn.setTitle("OK, entendi", for: [])
        infoLabel.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel.textColor = .white
        for v in [prevBtn, nextBtn, doneBtn, infoLabel] {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            controlContainer.addSubview(v)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            prevBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            prevBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            nextBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            nextBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            doneBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            doneBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
        nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        prevBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(prevTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        controlContainer.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        // we start with control container alpha at Zero
        controlContainer.alpha = 0.0
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        translucentLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    public func updateHole(_ r: CGRect, animated: Bool, cPos: ControlPosition) {
        
        translucentLayer.mask = holeLayer
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        
        // create a path for the "hole" in the layer
        var newR: CGRect = r
        newR.origin.x = 0.0
        newR.size.width = bounds.width
        let holePath = UIBezierPath(rect: newR)
        
        // this "cuts a hole" in the path
        path.append(holePath)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        newPath = path.cgPath
        
        if !animated {
            self.curPath = self.newPath
            self.holeLayer.path = self.curPath
        } else {
            // fade-out controlContainer
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.controlContainer.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { _ in
                // update next/prev/done buttons visiblity
                self.nextBtn.isHidden = self.currentState == 2 ? true : false
                self.prevBtn.isHidden = self.currentState == 0 ? true : false
                self.doneBtn.isHidden = !self.nextBtn.isHidden
                self.infoLabel.text = "Current State: \(self.currentState)"
        
                // update control container position
                self.ccTop.constant = cPos == .below ? r.maxY : r.minY - self.controlContainer.frame.height
                self.animPath()
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    private func animPath() {
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            // on animation completion, we want to
            //  update the holeLayer's path, and
            //  fade-in the controls container
            self.curPath = self.newPath
            self.holeLayer.path = self.curPath
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.controlContainer.alpha = 1.0
            })
        })
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
        
        // fromValue is not strictly necessary here, but we use it for consistency
        animation.fromValue = curPath
        animation.toValue = newPath
        
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        // adjust animation speed as desired
        animation.duration = 0.75
        
        holeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "positionAnimation")
        
        CATransaction.commit()
        
    }
    
    @objc func nextTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        currentState += 1
        onNextButtonTapped?()
    }
    @objc func prevTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        currentState -= 1
        onPrevButtonTapped?()
    }
    @objc func doneTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        onDoneButtonTapped?()
    }

}


Thank you my friend. I have no words to thank.
